# Include a file in laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am creating a project with some additional functionality provided in form of a .php file API which contains some functions and some classes(out of which some class names are conflicting with Laravel built in class names) so, my question how should I include this file in my Laravel Controller to call functions in the file which using the classes of the file without referring Laravel classes and with less or no modification in .php API file?

Note* I am using Laravel-5.1

Comment: What do you mean by saying that class names are conflicting? Since PHP 5.3 it is possible to have classes with the same name as long as they in different namespaces.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo The file contains Response class conflicting with Laravel Response class and few more classes

Comment: Sure, but is the response class in Illuminate\Http namespace?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Nope all the classes and functions in same file, only name conflict.

Comment: Ok, then include the file and alias the class names like in the answer below. You only need to alias the ones you are using in your controller.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo but where should I keep the file, if I want to merge it with Laravel and how the merge it with Laravel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87695/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-akshay-khale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for taking efforts in trying to solve my problem but none of the solution worked for me so, here is what I tried for my problem

Below is the structure of my php file that I wanted to includes/integrate

```
<?php

class Misc {

    const SUCCESS = 1;
    const FAILURE = 0;

    public static function get_hash ( $key )
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    public static function show_reponse ( $result )
    {
        ...
    }

}

function check($keyhash) 
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

function function2() 
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

class Response {

    public function __construct ( $key )
    {
        ...
    }

    public function __destruct ()
    {
        unset( $this->key );
        unset( $this->params );
    }

    public function __set ( $key)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function __get ( $key )
    {
        return $this->params[$key];
    }

    private function check_now ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The main problem I was facing is the class name `Response` which was conflicting with Laravel `Response` class so I just removed all classes from the file and moved to their individual files in a new folder in `Laravel\App` folder and added namespaces to all classes.

Then I moved all functions in a PHP file in `laravel\App` directory

and used classnames along with the namespace defined and since I moved all functions in a different PHP file I could easily call the functions

so here is my final folder structure of Laravel

Laravel

```
  -App
    -Console
    -Events
    -Exceptions
    -...
    -Libraries(Folder Containing Individual PHP files of classes from original file)
    -Providers
    -helpers.php(File containing all functions from original file)
    -User.php
  -bootstrap
  -...
  -...
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a custom file containing some classes/functions that need to be loaded for every request, you need to make sure it's added to the autoloader.

In your **composer.json** add the following in your **autoload** section:

```
"autoload": {
  "files": [
    "path/to/your/File.php"
  ]
}
```

This will make sure the file is loaded. Now what you need is a way to use those classes without conflicting with existing Laravel classes.

First, make sure you have a namespace declaration at the top of your included file - say **namespace Your\Namespace**. In order to avoid conflicts, you need to explicitly tell PHP which class you mean when you reference it in the code. You mentioned your file contains a **Response** class that also exists in Laravel. In order to be able to use both, you need to alias one of them:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response as LaravelResponse;
use Your\Namespace\Response;
```

Now in your code you can refer to Laravel's Response class as **LaravelResponse**, and to your response by simply **Response**.

Location of the file is irrelevant, as long as it's in a folder accessible to Laravel and its patch is added to **composer.json**.

Keep in mind that storing multiple classes per file is discouraged as a bad practice. I strongly suggest that you split your fine into separate file per class + one additional file with global functions.

Comment: location of the file is not relevant, it can be outside laravel's folder as well, but you need to update composer - and add the path to the folder

Answer (score 0):

Make an alias

Ex.

```
use App\Http\Requests\Request as DifferentRequest;

DifferentRequest->doStuff();
```

[Aliasing/Importing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: but where should I keep the file, if I want to merge it with Laravel and how the merge it with Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

make an alias as @user2504370 proposed,

add to the composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "place_with_your_file",
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "your_namespace": "your path",
    }
},
```

and run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

EDIT:
there was a typo in classmap. I wanted to tell you you can put your file whenever you want, for example, you can create a new folder 'place_with_your_file', which is not necessarily inside Laravel's folder.

I'm using it with my external libraries.

For PSR-4: if you are using namespaces, then here you will register the base namespace and the folder where can be found:

for example: `"Utilities\\": "../utilities/app"`

or whichever your path is.

and for classmap, you need to include path to this folder:

```
"../utilities/app"
```

and your autoload will look something like this:

```
   "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "../utilities/app",
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Utilities\\": "../utilities/app"`
        }
    },
```

Comment: This won't work as PSR-4 requires each class to be in a separate file with the same name as the class it contains. Here OP has a file that contains multiple classes and global functions.

Comment: actually, not true, it is registering namespace you use

Comment: Point 3.1 from PSR-4 specs: "The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name." - http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/.  It is registering a base folder for the namespace, but if you try to use a class from this space autoloader will try to load the file that has a name of the class. And the file will only be loaded when you use a class name that matches the file name - it won't be loaded automatically and it also won't be loaded when you try to use some global functions from this file.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I don't know what you are trying to say, I found a typo in my autoload classmap, so I extended my explanation, to make it more clear. And is working perfectly on all my applications :) Your explanations was not really clear to me, but thanks.